# How do i fix this pointer exception when im deleting an item in a database it crashes

Tags: java, android, database

Database manager:

```
public void deleteItem(int position){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete(CREATE_TABLE, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(position)} );
    database.close();
}
```

App logs:

> AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.clint.dailyremindertask.DatabaseManager.deleteItem(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: I would check to see if the database is not null. According to the error it is and you need to understand why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

NPE is thrown NOT in `deleteItem` method.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.clint.dailyremindertask.DatabaseManager.deleteItem(int)' on a null object reference.

This means your DatabaseManager is null, e.g:

```
DatabaseManager dm = null;
dm.deleteItem(42); // <- causes NPE with the same message
```